# Looking for feedback on switching power supply board design

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, switching-regulator

I'm currently designing a PCB for my first switching power supply using the LM2576, I've discovered while prototyping that these kinds of circuits are pretty sensitive to layout, rogue inductances and such.

I've had a read of various threads and other resources and tried to avoid making the same mistakes as others, now I'm just wondering if, in the opinion of people more experienced than me, I'm heading in the right direction with my layout or I should start again :')

First layout:

[image]

Updated layout:

[image]

Schematic:

[image]

Inductor: 100uH 5A, https://docs.rs-online.com/a3e0/0900766b81505738.pdf

Comment: You should add a schematic, links to the datasheet for your components and design specs, it will make it easier to check.  Something about your feedback divider looks off, but without a schematic it's hard to tell.

Comment: Maybe rotate D1 by 180 and connect over by C1 & R1 to decrease loop size.

Comment: Why would you want to deviate from the recommended design in datasheet for passive parts layout on loop size and orientation? Ref P 10.2  You are better off with SMT parts for ESR, ESL then use ground plane for heatsink. Where are your Noise and Thermal specs?

Comment: Add your schematic and a clear parts list. Copper directly under toroidal inductors without decent gap can be very problematic.

Comment: Better to spend more time planning with specs, if you can find any test results with existing designs. e.g. unknown design https://www.pcbway.com/blog/technology/How_to_build_an_adjustable_switching_power_supply_using_LM2576_[Buck_Converter__CC_CV].html   more https://www.google.com/search?q=LM2576+through+hole+layout&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk03KyB_ZztsCmCQhko75gjYDlS4Jvg:1591897157977&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=fpj6FiE6RTDhhM%253A%252CZpp9bgjjs6OhtM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTFVfjrhFEVTO3sieUtTDI4VXMfyQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj50vqEp_rpAhV0l3IEHZC2CP8Q9QEwA3oECBMQCw&biw=1664&bih=812

Comment: If you want low loop antenna noise, high current, you shrink the parts lower ESR, DCR,  e.g.  16A 5V https://www.datasheet.live/index.php?title=Special:PdfViewer&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdf.datasheet.live%2Fdatasheets-1%2Fericsson%2FPMA5118HS_SF.pdf

Comment: Why not run it in simulation then add 0.5nH/mm for traces and crosstalk in pF with mutual coupling. Does it drive a dynamic load? I see no loop filter compensation caps.

Comment: No matter how good or bad your design specs (measurable error goals) If it meets spec. it's  a perfect design but with no specs it's just design by "trial & error"

Comment: The feedback resistors are incorrect. It connects output to ground via resistor, and output to feedback pin via resistor. Please fix it. Layout-wise, yes it's according to instructions to take the feedback at the output capacitor, but you might want to connect the ground pin of feedback resistor closer to the chip ground pin, as now it is far away and the voltage at that point may have ripple due to copper resistance and input switching current.

Comment: To those that mentioned the feedback divider, thanks, though I already noticed that it was connected wrong, I drew that up at 3AM so it's really no surprise there's some errors :P
Aaron - Good shout with rotating D1.

Comment: I somehow managed to miss the entire section on PCB layout in the datasheet so thanks for pointing that out, it is quite helpful.
I was mostly looking for thoughts on the PCB layout itself though I probably should've included a bit more detail, I'll add a schematic.  It's very similar to the one in the datasheet but with dual output caps, an idea I actually got from that pcbway link Tony posted.
I've also updated the layout a bit now that I'm less sleep deprived.

Answer (score 1):

Your second layout looks good, nice job!

For radiated noise the priority is minimizing your hot loop: Current out of Cin to Pin1, out Pin 2 to diode, out diode to ground, back to Cin. I'd probably widen the line from pin 2 to the diode a lot. As was mentioned in a comment, moving to SMT parts will improve ESL and ESR to some degree. You have everything well routed on the top layer so the vias don't really matter, it's just that SMT components are better. What you've got looks good but we're always paranoid and do everything we can, right?

This is more a design than layout comment, but... A priority for output voltage ripple is Cout value and ESR. Try to get close to the 30mOhm limit of that part (per the datasheet) for the big caps, combined. I'd consider adding a high frequency capacitor on the output. The switcher is only at ~50kHz but the rising/falling edges of the switching waveforms are very fast and will be well into the MHz or 10's of MHz of content. So, put room for one or two 1uF SMT caps on the output.

I don't think it would actually matter but I'd pull the ground plane closer to pin 3 to minimize that trace length/inductance.

I prefer larger annular rings for L1 and U1 thru-holes. For rework of U1 for example you might heat and reheat the leads several times trying to get all the solder out. It's easy to delaminate the annular rings when doing that. Same for L1. For hand soldering, I make those annular rings pretty huge.

Another personal preference is that I'd add a pair of 0.1" header pin vias on the board for Vin, gnd, and Vout. I'd solder a loop of wire on those so I could easily clip multiple test leads on them (ez hooks and o'scope, alligator clips, etc.). A single pin can be annoying with multiple leads connected, for me, anyway.

Again, nice work it's looking quite good. If you fabbed it as is I think you'd be quite happy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, appreciate it!
I'll take all that on board and make some tweaks before I get it made, I may do another with SMT components in the future but the idea for this one is for it to be easy to hand-solder, though I'll still add some pads for extra output caps as you recommend, might as well have the option there right.
Good idea for making connections too, I might give that a go.